# creating a dataframe from a.character column in another dataframe containing a list of elements in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame (dt)

```
id          genre                                       score
1           "action & adventure, sci-fi, comedy"           10
2           "sci-fi"                                        7
3           "action & adventure"                            8
4           "fantasy, comedy"                               2

...
```

I basically want to create a table with each genre and the mean score per sum of score per genre

in this case it would be

```
     genre                   score

     action & adventure      18
     sci-fi                  17
     fantasy                  2
     comedy                  12
```

I m sure there is some elegant way to do it, but the only thing I can think of is creating a series of dummies in dt for each genre and then multiply it for the score and then sum the elements per each column.
thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dplyr way...

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% separate_rows(genre,sep = ",") %>% 
mutate_at(vars(genre), str_trim) %>% 
group_by(genre) %>% 
summarise(sum_score = sum(score, na.rm = T),
          mean_score = mean(score, na.rm = T))
```

output as

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  genre              sum_score mean_score
  <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl>
1 action & adventure        18        9  
2 comedy                    12        6  
3 fantasy                    2        2  
4 sci-fi                    17        8.5
```